# How to prevent Intellij Idea from switching between open files when compilation errors occure?

Tags: intellij-idea

Whenever I edit code and save the current file, IntelliJ executes the compilation which is normal and a wanted behavior. But everytime a compilation error occures, it opens the files that contain the errors which is very annoying ( I'm not done yet since I'm still editing the code ) .

Is there a way to prevent that behavior other than disabling the auto-compile ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

File / Settings / Build, Execution, Deployment / Compiler / disable Automatically show first error on build.

Answer (score 4):

Go to `Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler` and uncheck `Automatically show first error in editor`.